# What does "transmogrify" mean?

Tags: support, privileges

In the last image of the [privilege description of "access to moderator tools"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), there is a button named "transmogrify". What does it mean?

[image: Inline tag edits]

The dictionary entry makes it more confusing:

> ### trans·mog·ri·fy
>
> Verb
>   Transform, esp. in a surprising or magical manner.

In addition to the image on MSO, the SO image seems to have the print and transmogrify text as well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: This is a joke I suppose?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Probably a reference to the [Transmogrifier](http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Transmogrifier).

Comment: This was a vocabulary word my father made certain I knew at about age 8.  No joke; he had a penchant for odd words, and teaching such to his children.

Comment: It's a tool that lets you turn tags into lizards, but it needs to be upside-down to work. If it's right-side-up, then it's a time machine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oh, my. I really should start disabling my userscripts when taking screenshots. The entry [was added by me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/19), and I had the transmogrifier enabled at the time.

That and the print item are like macros that help me, but are not part of the site coding.

Comment: [Someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196252/what-is-transmogrification) was confused by your screen shot.  You might want to correct it.

Comment: I've untransmogrified the screen picture - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66326/revisions

Comment: @bmike It still visible at http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools .

Comment: @Marc-Andre It takes some time to sync over.

Comment: @Manishearth I wasn't aware of that sorry. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I would think 16 hours would be enough time? I don't have edit capabilities on SO so if it doesn't self correct, someone may I've to poke that post as well.

Comment: @bmike Not necessarily, it can take weeks, too. The faq syncing isn't fast... Or it wan't fast in the past, at any rate.

Comment: Take my advice, never screenshot anything on SE unless done in an incognito window :/

Comment: @Won't Ah, you would know :) I generally do look out for what I can't expose before taking a screenshot, however most of my screenshots require me to be logged in so incog doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

[Transmogrify](https://stackapps.com/questions/3477/transmogrify-offtopic-mso-posts) is a now defunct userscript for quickly dealing with off-topic Meta questions. The author of the screenshot must have been using it. It automatically cast close and down votes and responded to the post with a Calvin and Hobbes strip, along with a message along the lines of:

> I'm so glad you asked me that, but I have no clue how to solve it.
>   Have a Calvin & Hobbes strip instead!

Comment: I loved that userscript :P I believe the print button is also a userscript...

Comment: Yup. As seen in [revision 19 of the privilege page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66326/revisions), [Manishearth](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth) was the one who added the screenshot.