# What is "Transmogrification"?

Tags: discussion

In the help center under the moderator tools privilege, there is an interesting screenshot.

[image]

I assume that this picture was taken while logged in as Jeff Atwood on Meta Stack Overflow.

In this picture, I can see "print" and "transmogrify" buttons beneath the question. It's pretty obvious what "print" means, but what about "transmogrify?" And what privilege levels do you need to see these buttons?

Comment: It's a userscript.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this - I've untransmogrified the screen picture - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66326/revisions

Comment: @bmike Good job. Was that photoshop, or what?

Comment: I just dumped the image into [skitch](http://evernote.com/skitch/) and drew some white rectangles over the two pipe symbols, print and transmogrify. So basically yes, I shopped it but for less money and far faster than I could launch PS.